# How to handle links in Phonegap + JQM app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am building an app with Phonegap and jQuerymobile. The app roughly works like this:

1) The app downloads a ZIP file from a public server and then unzips them to a local folder. I got the local folder path from `fileSystem.root.toNativeURL()` (in OS, it's something like this:  `file://var/mobile/Container/Data/Application/xxxx/Documents/`)

2) App redirects to HTML that was unzipped in local folder (ex: `file://var/mobile/Container/Data/Application/xxxx/Documents/index.html`)

I am now facing issues b/c inside the index.html file, all the links are absolute path (ex: `<a href="/content/index2.html">Link</a>`). This breaks all the links since (I assume) they are all now pointing to `file://content/index2.html` instead of `file://var/mobile/Container/Data/Application/xxxx/Documents/content/index2.html`.

My question is, how should I handle the links? I am thinking i should just rewrite all the links to force prepend the local folder URL in front of it. Is there a better way?

And if rewriting links is the way to go, how can I do this with jQuerymobile? I did this in jQuery which seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/jg4ouqc5/ but this code doesn't work in my app (jQueryMobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are loading index.html, you are getting file://some_path/..../index.html as your base URL. Any links which will be encountered now own-wards can be resolved in relation to the base URL.

You would know your scenario better. There could be multiple ways in which this can be fixed.

- Have a contract with the CMS/Code generator. Links should always be generated either **Relative to the base URL or Absolute**. The links you are getting in the page are wrong - `<a href="/content/index2.html">Link</a>` it ideally should be `<a href="content/index2.html">Link</a>` or fully qualified like `https://www.google.com`.
- If you want to change the URL then you can use native code to change it after unzipping the content. It will be really straight forward.
- If you want to change the URL in browser then you will have to persist the base url and then take care of couple of things:

  **a.** absolute urls - In your case you can just check the window.location.protocol, if it starts with 'http' and then skip it.

  **b.** sub-directories

Here is a small I have written:
**Note: I have not tried this code and you might have to change it according to your need.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var base_file_name = window.location.pathname.substring(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        //In index.html (persist this value in native)
        var baseUrl = window.location.href.replace(base_file_name, "");

        $("a").each(function () {
            this.href =  baseUrl + this.pathname;
            $(this).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(this.pathname);
                window.location.href = this.href;
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing the javascript way similar to yours. Except since I am on JQM I had to change the document.ready... to document.on('pagecreate'... and a few other things. the rest is the same, more or less. I was hesitant on going the javascript way (feels hack-ish) but it seems to be the only way I can think of...

Comment: Glad you were able to achieve it. :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked should work, make sure you have the `<base>` set correctly and that you are using the correct string to replace.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, your going to have to normalize all URL's when your page loads.  I can't test with phonegap right now, but your `basePath` will need to be one of the following:

- The file path as you described in your answer (not likely)
- `window.location.origin` (optionally including `window.location.pathname`)

CODE:

```
// mini dom ready - https://github.com/DesignByOnyx/mini-domready
(function(e,t,n){var r="attachEvent",i="addEventListener",s="DOMContentLoaded";if(!t[i])i=t[r]?(s="onreadystatechange")&&r:"";e[n]=function(r){/in/.test(t.readyState)?!i?setTimeout(function(){e[n](r)},9):t[i](s,r,false):r()}})
(window,document,"domReady");

domReady(function () {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName['a'],
        basePath = /* get your base path here, without a trailing slash */;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function( anchor ){
        anchor.setAttribute('href', basePath + anchor.getAttribute('href'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the forward slash from the beginning of your links.

```
href="content/index2.html">
```

Comment: I can't, the HTML is generated by a CMS. Also if i make the link relative, how do we handle deeper folders?